# Best way to structure site files before going live

Tags: django, directory-structure

I have built a website using Django and I'm about to go live. I had a question about the structuring of CSS files before I publish.

Currently my site looks like this

```
-Root
   -App 1
      -App 1 Files
   -App 2
      -App 2 Files
   -App 3
      -App 3 Files
   -mysite
      -Templates
         -App 1 Templates
         -App 2 Templates
         -App 3 Templates
      -Static
         -Images
         -CSS Files
         -JS
```

My main css was quite large so I split it up into separate css files for each section.

I'm wondering if it would make sense to place the css files next to their corresponding templates, or if it would be best to leave them in the static folder as they are now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that this isn't really the type of question that SO is for, and this question may be removed.

But the way you have it currently is standard convention. It allows there to be a standardized way of grabbing the static files in a template. If you ever have to change them in the future, you'll know exactly where they are, and any Django developer would as well (especially if you follow a good naming scheme). Unless you have a good reason to change that, then I would refrain from doing so; you'll thank yourself (or perhaps someone else will) down the road.

[The docs on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/) state that all files in the `STATIC_ROOT` directory will be included in the static folders, which should include the templates anyway. So from a technical standpoint, it will be fine. You'll just be deviating from the standard convention.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is the first time I've built something outside of localhost so I have a lot of questions regarding best practices. I will plan on sticking with the current structure, I think keeping it the way I have it now is less confusing!